# Getting an error when trying the IF ELSE statements but same function works with if_else, why? Coupling case_when

Tags: r, if-statement, case

I have a dataframe (cd) with 6 columns and 105 rows. I wrote two different codes, one using **if_else** (this works fine) and the other using **IF ELSE** for which I am getting an error.

The if_else code works perfectly and is as seen below:

```
cd %>% mutate(height.diff = 
                if_else(cd$gender == "male", 
              case_when(height < 160 ~ "short",
                        height >= 160 & height < 175 ~"medium",
                        height >= 175 ~ "tall"),
                case_when(height < 155 ~ "short",
                        height >= 155 & height < 160 ~"medium",
                        height >= 160 ~ "tall")))
```

But when I run it with IF and ELSE:

```
cd %>% drop_na(height) %>% mutate(height.diff = 
                if (cd$gender == "male") {
              case_when(height < 160 ~ "short",
                        height >= 160 & height < 175 ~"medium",
                        height >= 175 ~ "tall",
                        TRUE ~ NA_character_) }
              else {
                case_when(height < 155 ~ "short",
                        height >= 155 & height < 160 ~"medium",
                        height >= 160 ~ "tall",
                        TRUE ~ NA_character_) 
                }
              )
```

I get the following error message:
*Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "call_text", value = c("cd %>% drop_na(height) %>% ...",  :
replacement has 10 rows, data has 4*

As you can see, I also added extra lines of code to try removing potential NA values, but that didn't work either and I still get the same error. Can't figure out why I'm getting an error for this despite the similar codes.

Thank you!

Comment: `if/else` is not vectorized Perhaps you meant `if(all(gender == "male"))`

Comment: Hi akrun, thanks for the quick reply. Indeed the code does now with your suggestion, but I don't get any output (the console just prints the code in blue). Any ideas for this? Thanks again!

Comment: You havent assigned back i.e. `cd <- cd %>% ..`

Comment: gotcha, thanks! so does the *all in the revised code you wrote makes it check each value 1 by 1 or what does it do exactly (in regards to if/else not being vectorized)?

Comment: It implies that `if/else` expects a single TRUE/FALSE as input.  The number of rows of your data may be greater than 1, thus it returns a logical vector of length > 1